# How to get metrics of Local persistent volume (kubernetes)

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, persistent-volumes

I created local persistent volume on my k8s cluster and I would like to monitor it with prometheus.
Unfortunately, It looks like there is no possibility to get it by /metrics of nodes.
I found "kube_persistentvolumeclaim_resource_requests_storage_bytes" metrics who list the volumes with requested sizes but I don't find any metric to get the current usage of this disk space.

Do you know if it is possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing **[Prometheus node_exporter](https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/node-exporter/)** component for collecting the metrics from all nodes across the cluster including local persistent volumes. Installing and using the node_exporter is an easy process You can download the **node_exporter** from this [**official page**](https://prometheus.io/download/#node_exporter).

In your case you can run this node_exporter as a dameon set as something like this

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Daemonset
metadata:
 name: node-exporter
 namespace: mynamespace
 labels:
  app: node-exporter
spec:
 selector:
  matchLabels:
   app: node-exporter
 template:
  metatada:
   labels:
    app: node-exporter
  spec:
   containers:
    - name: node-exporter
      image: prom/node-exporter:latest
      ports:
      - containerPort: 9100
        name: metrics
      volumeMounts:
      - name: sys
        mountPath: /host/sys
        readOnly: true
      - name: root
        mountPath: /host/root
        readOnly: true
      args:
      - --web.listen-address=:9100
      - --path.procfs=/host/proc
      - --path.sysfs=/host/sys
      - --collector.filesystem.ignored-mount-points=^/(dev|var/lib/docker/.+)($|/)
    volumes:
     - name: sys
       hostpath:
         path: /sys
     - name: root
       hostpath:
         path: /
```

This daemon set runs the node_exporter in every node and collects the respective metrics. Here we are ignoring the cmd --`collector.filesystem.ignored-mount-points` to exclude the certain mount points like /var/lib/docker.

Once you deploy node_exporter, you should be able to query the disk usage metrics using prometheus. Some of the query examples are

- `node_filesystem_size_bytes{mountpoint="/mnt/my_pv_disk"}` This query will return the total size of the local persistent disk
- `node_filesystem_free_bytes{mountpoint="/mnt/my_pv_disk"}` This will return the amount of free space on the persistent disk
- You can subtract the total size with free space, you will get the usage of the disk like as follows `node_filesystem_size_bytes{mountpoint="/"} - node_filesystem_free_bytes{mountpoint="/"}`

**Note: You can change the mount point path to get the metrics of respective paths**

You can explore more collectors of node_exporter by referring the [official github page](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter#enabled-by-default)

Comment: Hi @MelaniOL did you get a chance to look at this answer? is it helpful?